# How to get a getter of a property?

Tags: c#, properties

I would like to get a getter of a property so I could pass to a method that requires Func. For now I extracted getter to a Get method and I use this method when I need the getter function.

Few words about background: I have class A with properties and I have another class T which keeps track of some properties from A (and from class B, C, etc.). Keeping track means here that when object of T is asked about current values of tracked properties it should give such.

One approach could be change notification mechanism, but class A does not know what is tracked or not -- so it is quite wrong approach. You have to rewrite all classes that **might** be tracked. Moreover notifications have to be send all the time, even if tracker won't be asked about values at all.

It seems more handy to simply pass a method how to read the value (getter of property) and tracker will use it when required. No overhead, pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiled code, or reflection? As a delegate, you can just use:

```
Func<Foo, int> func = x => x.SomeValue;
```

or to track the *specific* object:

```
Func<int> funct = () => someObj.SomeValue;
```

With reflection you would need `GetGetMethod()` and `Delegate.CreateDelegate()`

Comment: This is why we are all going nuts about lambdas in c# ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
var getter = typeof(DateTime).GetProperty("Now").GetGetMethod();
var func = Delegate.CreateDelegate(getter, typeof(Func<DateTime>)) 
               as Func<DateTime>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another variant:

```
Func<int> getCurrentValue = delegate { return IntValue; };
```